# CSS Transition works when adding class, but not removing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

First off, just wanted to mention that I have read this thread:

[CSS3 transition only when class is added, not when removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646233/css3-transition-only-when-class-is-added-not-when-removed)

and the solution there does not work for me. I have a nav that is hidden when the browser is within the small breakpoint, and is revealed when an element is clicked. Clicking the element adds a class via jQuery. Once open, there is a close button that when clicked removes the class. The class is adding and subtracting as expected, but for some reason the transition only works when the .open class is added, not when it's removed. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-main-nav-container">
    <ul id="menu-main-nav" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href="http://blackandwright.com/what-we-do">What We Do</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41"><a href="http://blackandwright.com/team">Team</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-42"><a href="http://blackandwright.com/case-studies">Case Studies</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-102"><a href="http://blackandwright.com/what-next">What Next?</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-104"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-122"><a href="#close">Close</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS (Compass + Sass):

```
#menu-main-nav {
    @include single-transition(opacity, 0.3s, ease-in-out);

    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -27px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 5000;

    &.open {
        opacity: 1;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

CSS (Compiled):

```
#header #menu-main-nav {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -27px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 5000;
} 
#header #menu-main-nav.open {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.menu-main-nav-container', function(e) {
        if(!$mobileNav.hasClass('open')) {
            $mobileNav.addClass('open');
        }
    }).on('click', '.nav-close', function(e) {
        if($mobileNav.hasClass('open')) {
            $mobileNav.removeClass('open');
        }
    })
});
```

I'm pretty stumped here. Keep in mind that I am using Compass and that the initial transition is working as expected.

Comment: Can you add your compiled CSS and/or create an MCVE?

Comment: It's because the `height` goes from `0` to `auto` instantly. This is ok when you add class `.open`, because the animation happens after the `height` expands to `auto`. But you don't see the animation when the `.open` class is removed, because the `height` goes to `0` first and then the animation happens.

Comment: @SuviVignarajah I tried including a transition (still the same easing function and duration) to the height and changing height: auto to height: 300px (because if I'm not mistaken css transitions will not work with height: auto) and the problem persists. When the .open class is added, the menu fades in and drops down (increases in height). However when I click a second time, it just disappears suddenly as before.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Just added the relevant lines of the compiled CSS file

Comment: @SuviVignarajah is right about why it happens. Here's an example of making it work with fixed height. https://jsfiddle.net/c10n8juh/ There are different ways you could solve this. Why are you changing the `height` and `opacity`?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara this Fiddle got me the solution. I think that I was misunderstanding how the transitions work. I was using the compass mixin "single-transition" and wasn't including a delay. I tried using two "single transition" mixins using the same delays that you have here, but that didn't work. What did work is using the plain ol' "transition" mixin for compass. If you or Suvi would like to submit an official answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is that `height: 0` immediately hides the element when the class is removed. The opacity still transitions, but you don't see it.

Unfortunately, since `height: auto` is not a transitionable value, adding a height to the transition is not going to help. You could do it with a fixed height, if you set a delay when the open class is not present, but remove the delay when it is added.

```js
var $menu = $('#menu-main-nav');
setInterval(function() {
    $menu.toggleClass('open');
}, 2000);
```

```css
#menu-main-nav {
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s, height 0s 1s;
}
#menu-main-nav.open {
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s, height 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-main-nav-container">
    <ul id="menu-main-nav" class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What Next?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#close">Close</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As an alternative to fixed `height`, if you do not rely on the layout of the element when expanded, you could use `visibility` which is transitionable (well, you can delay it by a transition anyway), using the same technique above.

```js
var $menu = $('#menu-main-nav');
setInterval(function() {
    $menu.toggleClass('open');
}, 2000);
```

```css
#menu-main-nav {
    background: grey;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 1s, visibility 0s 1s;
}
#menu-main-nav.open {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: opacity 1s, visibility 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-main-nav-container">
    <ul id="menu-main-nav" class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What Next?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#close">Close</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, this means that the element will always the same height. If you do need the element to have a variable height, you could use JavaScript to calculate the target height, and set it to a fixed height for the duration of the animation.

Comment: Thank you! The height isn't actually needed, so this solution works

Answer (score 0):

try this, you just forgot the "" in your body element, and put the elements inside ()
Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on('click', '.menu-main-nav-container', function(e) {
        if(!$("mobileNav").hasClass('open')) {
            $("mobileNav").addClass('open');
        }
    }).on('click', '.nav-close', function(e) {
        if($("mobileNav").hasClass('open')) {
            $("mobileNav").removeClass('open');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I actually _did_ have the quotes but somehow they got removed in my pasting. I think I pasted all but the $('body') part and then forgot to add them in when I typed it. Unfortunately this is not the problem. I've confirmed that the class is successfully added and removed.